# Postgres triggers and producers (column "new" of relation does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger and procedure to update a `last_changed_timestamp` column upon UPDATE and INSERT.

I can register the function and trigger just fine, but when I try to update a record I receive the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_my_table_last_changed_timestamp()
        RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
        UPDATE my_table SET NEW.last_changed_timestamp = NOW();  
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_my_table_last_changed_timestamp 
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_my_table_last_changed_timestamp();
```

`column "new" of relation "my_table" does not exist`

I also do not fully understand how `update_my_table_last_changed_timestamp` knows which row it's suppose to update, nor if there were parameters passed to it, how the I would get those variables from the trigger to the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the NEW record, there is no need to update.

```
BEGIN
    NEW.last_changed_timestamp = NOW();  
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Read in the documentation: [Overview of Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/trigger-definition.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to access a (other )table in the update trigger.

You can add to beginning of your trigger body the following:

```
EXECUTE format('SET search_path TO %I', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA);
```

For some reason with the update trigger it can happen that you're not on the correct search_path (i believe some old psql version have this)